# Office 365 Management Activity API - Audit.SharePoint returns event out of the time frame

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, office365api

I'm working against the Office 365 Management Activity API and trying to get system events for a time frame. e.g. I want to get create folder events between 2018-11-21T16:58:43.4970000Z and 2018-11-21T16:58:46.5407833Z.
I'm sending this request first:
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/1111/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Sharepoint&startTime=2018-11-21T16:58:43.4970000Z&endTime=2018-11-21T16:58:46.5407833Z&PublisherIdentifier=11111

and based on the response I send the second request:
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/11111/activity/feed/audit/20181121165257926082320$20181121165843497120740$audit_sharepoint$Audit_Sharepoint?PublisherIdentifier=11111

I get event list in the response. The problem is that I get events with creation time which is earlier then I defined in the requests (2018-11-21T16:55:09):

> {**"CreationTime":"2018-11-21T16:55:09"**,"Id":"*****","Operation":"FolderCreated","OrganizationId":"********","RecordType":6,"UserKey":"i:0h.f|membership|******@live.com","UserType":0,"Version":1,"Workload":"OneDrive","ClientIP":"******","ObjectId":"https://spenterprise501-my.sharepoint.com/personal/admin_501_blabla_com/Documents/am1/amir444","UserId":"admin@501.blabla.com","CorrelationId":"******","EventSource":"SharePoint","ItemType":"Folder","ListId":"49fc3d8e-5345-4225-867f-451a753331eb","ListItemUniqueId":"b15f342b-5812-4ad9-9077-ce5c5454c4b1","Site":"014fe483-77db-4234-9245-fa144534d88fa","UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36","WebId":"be54eb7-0f23-45bc-8540-389fbed45359","SourceFileExtension":"","SiteUrl":"https://spenterprise501-my.sharepoint.com/personal/admin_501_blabla_com/","SourceFileName":"amir444","SourceRelativeUrl":"Documents/am1"}

The strange thing is that every event (e.g. "FolderCreated") I'm getting twice. One in the correct time frame and the second when another event is created, even if the start time I'm defining is much bigger than the original event creation time...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do I get in the bucket event with creation time that is earlier than the bucket start time. And why do I get this event twice in two separate buckets - once in a "correct" bucket  and the second in the wrong one.